# C language, xcode, card game

Tags: c

For a school project I am trying to make the card game go fish. So far I have it so that it creates a deck in a doubly linked list either from a file (for testing specific combinations), or from some for loops within the main. I can then take that deck and shuffle it around and print the cards. I am having a difficult time figuring out how to deal out seven cards per two players. I have an idea where I create hand1 and hand2 and then take the first seven cards from the list, copy them to hand1 and then delete them from the list. Same with hand2. This system would also be useful in either grabbing a card from the deck (go fish) or from stealing a card from the second player. How would I implement something like this in code? Here is an example of my code thus far. Any help would be appreciated and would help me understand what is going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct card_s{
    char suit[7];
    int value;
    struct card_s *next, *previous;
}card;

int rand_gen(int count){
    double frac;
    frac = (double)rand()/((double)RAND_MAX+1);
    return floor(count * frac); //random number in [0, count]
}

void deleteMember(card *p, card **hl, card **hr) {
     if (p == *hl){         // if deleting the first element
        *hl = p->next;
     }
 // update the left headp
     else{
     p->previous->next = p->next;
     }

     if (p == *hr){
     *hr = p->previous;     // if deleting the last element
     }
     else{
     p->next->previous = p->previous;
     }

free(p); // free memory
}

void addCard(card *p, card **hl, card **hr, FILE *inp){

card *temp; // pointer to a node_t
temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof (card)); // new node creation

       fscanf(inp, "%d", &temp->value);
fscanf(inp, "%s", temp->suit);

                    if (*hl == NULL){ // if left head is null, i.e., list is empty
                        temp->previous = NULL;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                        *hl = temp;
                        *hr = temp;
                    }
                    else if (p->next == NULL){ // if adding at the end of list
                        temp->previous = p;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                        p->next = temp;
                        *hr = temp;
                    }
                    else{     // if adding to the middle of the list
                        temp->next = p-> next;
                        temp->previous = p;
                        p->next = temp;
                        temp->next->previous = temp;
                    }
                    }
void addCard1(card *p, card **hl, card **hr, int value, char suit[7]){

card *temp; // pointer to a node_t
temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof (card)); // new node creation
temp->value = value;
strcpy(temp->suit, suit);

if (*hl == NULL){ // if left head is null, i.e., list is empty
    temp->previous = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    *hl = temp;
    *hr = temp;
}
else if (p->next == NULL){ // if adding at the end of list
    temp->previous = p;
    temp->next = NULL;
    p->next = temp;
    *hr = temp;
}
else{     // if adding to the middle of the list
    temp->next = p-> next;
    temp->previous = p;
    p->next = temp;
    temp->next->previous = temp;
}
}

void Print(card **headl)  { //this function prints from left to right only
    card *temp;
    temp = (*headl);
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("|");
        printf("%d", temp->value);
        if(strcmp(temp->suit,"hea")==0) {
            printf("♥");
        }
        if(strcmp(temp->suit,"clu")==0) {
            printf("♣");
        }
        if(strcmp(temp->suit,"spa")==0) {
            printf("♠");
        }
        if(strcmp(temp->suit,"dia")==0) {
            printf("♦");
        }
        printf("|");
        //printf("%s ", temp->suit);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
void Print1(card **headl)  { //this function prints from left to right only
card *temp;
temp = (*headl);
while(temp != NULL) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    printf("|");
        if(temp->value == 11){
           printf("J");
        }
        else if(temp->value == 12) {
            printf("Q");
        }
        else if(temp->value == 13) {
            printf("K");
        }
        else if(temp->value == 14) {
            printf("A");
        }
        else {
            printf("%d", temp->value);
        }

    if(strcmp(temp->suit,"h")==0) {
        printf("♥");
    }
    if(strcmp(temp->suit,"c")==0) {
        printf("♣");
    }
    if(strcmp(temp->suit,"s")==0) {
        printf("♠");
    }
    if(strcmp(temp->suit,"d")==0) {
        printf("♦");
    }
    printf("|");

    //printf("%s ", temp->suit);
    temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}

void swap(card *pt, int i, int j) {
int i1 = i;
int j1 = j;

if(i1 == j1) {
    j1 = j1 + 1;
}

card *temp;
temp = (card *)malloc(sizeof(card));
card *temp1 = pt, *temp2 = pt;  //creates temperaries that start from the head left

for(int x = 0; x < i1; x++) { //counts the number of nodes until i
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}

for(int x = 0; x < j1; x++) { //counts the number of nodes until j
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}
temp->value = temp1->value;  //swaps the information not the nodes
strcpy(temp->suit,temp1->suit);
temp1->value = temp2->value;
strcpy(temp1->suit, temp2->suit);
temp2->value = temp->value;
strcpy(temp2->suit, temp->suit);

}

int main(void)  {
FILE *inp = NULL;
char player1[20];
char player2[20];
char y;
int i = 0;
char heart[]= "h";
char diamond[] = "d";
char clubs[] = "c";
char spades[] = "s";
inp = fopen("cards.txt", "r");
srand((int)time(NULL));
card *headl = NULL, *headr = NULL;

if(inp == NULL) {
    printf("No file found");
    return -1;
}

printIntro();

printf("\n");

printf("Player one enter your name: ");
fgets(player1, sizeof(player1)-2, stdin);
char *pos;
if ((pos=strchr(player1, '\n')) != NULL) //this it get rid of the enter in the string
    *pos = '\0';

printf("Player two enter your name: ");
fgets(player2, sizeof(player2)-2, stdin);
i = 0;
char *pos1;
if ((pos1=strchr(player2, '\n')) != NULL)
    *pos1 = '\0';

printf("Welcome %s and %s", player1, player2);
printf("\n");

printf("Would you like to load a preloaded deck (y/n): ");
scanf(" %c", &y);

if(y =='y' || y =='Y') {
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        addCard(headr, &headl, &headr, inp);
    }
}
else {
    for(int i = 2; i<15; i++) {
        addCard1(headr, &headl, &headr, i, heart);
    }
    for(int i = 2; i<15; i++) {
        addCard1(headr, &headl, &headr, i, diamond);
    }
    for(int i = 2; i<15; i++) {
        addCard1(headr, &headl, &headr, i, clubs);
    }
    for(int i = 2; i<15; i++) {
        addCard1(headr, &headl, &headr, i, spades);
    }
}

Print1(&headl);

printf("\n");
printf("\n");

for(int i = 0; i <= 152; i++) {  //does the swap function swap number times
        swap(headl, rand_gen(52), rand_gen(52));
       }

Print1(&headl);

return(0);
}
```

EDIT: I have tried this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    addCard1(hand1r, &hand1l, &headr, headr->value, headr->suit);
    deleteMember(headl, &headl, &headr);
}
```

But, it gives me an error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)" on the addmember1 function on the else if portion.

EDIT 2: I found what was wrong.
This is what I call to have to implement hands

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    addCard1(hand1r, &hand1l, &hand1r, headl->value, headl->suit);
    deleteMember(headl, &headl, &headr);
}
 Print(&hand1l);
printf("\n");

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    addCard1(hand2r, &hand2l, &hand2r, headl->value, headl->suit);
    deleteMember(headl, &headl, &headr);
}
Print(&hand2l);
```

Comment: The basic concept is to never `free` a card. The deck is a linked list. Each hand is a linked list. And cards played on the table are a linked list. So all you need is to take a card from the deck, and add it to a hand. Or take a card from a hand, and play it on the table. That's accomplished simply by changing the `next` and `previous` pointers.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm just not sure how I would make the hand linked list and then transer the node from the deck.